# Angular: force custom form validator to run on any field input

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-validation

I've written a custom validator for a password field, in order to verify the following scenarios:

- if user has id defined, then password is always valid (can be empty, meaning no change)
- if user does not have id defined, then password must not be empty (new users must have a password)

Problem is, I have noticed the validator is run only when the user interacts with the field (unlike `required` which is run on any input apparently). This makes the form appear valid even if password empty for a new user. Once I interact with the password input, everything seems fine.

I have solved the business logic requirement through the poorly documented `ngRequired` directive, but I would really like to understand the issue regarding the custom validator in case I run into it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After giving up on this, I ran into the problem again and I could not find a workaround. Fortunatel, I found a solution:

When you make a custom validator you need to bind it to the model field, not the form field. This makes it validate correctly all the time (one can assume due to differences between $modelValue and $viewValue properties that are on the form field which fudges up things). Please see code below for reference:

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmpass" name="confirmpass" placeholder="Repeat Password"
                       ng-model="controller.selectedUser.passwordRepeat"
                       compare-to="controller.selectedUser.password"/>
```

And custom validator:

```
angular.module("compareTo", []).directive("compareTo", function() {
   return {
       require: "ngModel",
       scope: {
       otherModelValue: "=compareTo"
   },
   link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {

       ngModel.$validators.compareTo = function(modelValue) {
           return modelValue == scope.otherModelValue;
       };

       scope.$watch("otherModelValue", function() {
           ngModel.$validate();
       });
   }
  };
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ui-validate](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-validate) with your business here:

```
$scope.passwordValidation = {
                length: '$value.length >= 5 || $value.length == 0'
            };
$scope.password2Validation = {
                same_passwords: 'userPassword.value==$value'
            };
```

And then your HTML:

```
<input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" ng-model="userPassword.value"
                   name="password" ui-validate="passwordValidation"/>
<input id="password2" class="form-control" type="password" ng-model="userPassword.confirm"
                   name="password2" ui-validate="password2Validation" ui-validate-watch="'userPassword.value'"/>
```

Please note the `ui-validate-watch` to tell ui-validate to care about the other password field.

Comment: That seems like a good solution to the overall issue, but I would be really curious to understand why the custom validator didn't work as intended.